# javascript passing variables to the next page (without php)

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I am a beginner in html and javascript so your help will be much appreciated.

I am creating a page that accepts values x and y from a form and enters it into a graph.

The graph is working perfectly on the same web page but i would like to have the graph in an entirely different page after I click the submit button. How can i carry forward these variables to a different page and display the same graph? (I would like to avoid JQuery, php etc altogether as this is for a school project)

Here's my code:

```
function someFunction(){

var xScore = parseFloat(x)
var yScore = parseFloat(y)

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['x', 'y'],
      [ xScore ,      yScore],

    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Sample Graph',
      hAxis: {title: 'x value', minValue: 1, maxValue: 9},
      vAxis: {title: 'y value', minValue: 1, maxValue: 9},
      legend: 'none'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

This chart loads when i place following the div in the body.

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 900px;">
```

I would like to place this div in the body of another html page but would like to carry forward the x and y values generated on this web page (they are generated when the form is submitted).

Comment: How about using the local storage?

Comment: Using a query string?

Comment: Are those pages on the **same domain**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use window.localStorage

Put the following literal object in some `js` file that you will refer to from the current and the next page (or just paste the object wherever necessary).

```
var xyStore =
    {
        GetX: function () {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("x"));                
        },
        GetY: function () {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("y"));                
        },
        SetX: function (x) {
            localStorage.setItem("x", JSON.stringify(x));
        },
        SetY: function (y) {
            localStorage.setItem("y", JSON.stringify(y));
        },
   };
```

use in current page:

```
xyStore.SetX(12);
```

use in next page:

```
alert(xyStore.GetX()); // alerts: 12
```

**EDIT**

Following  @RokoC.Buljan comment, this functionality can be expanded as follows:

```
            Get: function (name) {
                return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(name));                
            },
            Set: function (name, val) {
                localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(val));
            }
```

Comment: Why `GetX-Y`A-Z ? isn't it simpler to pass the **desired** LS db **name** trough an argument?

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for the quick response it solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple form on the first page that is configured with `method="GET"` and `action="/page2.html"`. The input fields within the form should also have a `name` attribute filled in, for example `<input name="x">`. Then when you press the submit button in your form, it will pass along the field names and values as a querystring to the second page. For example `/graph.html?x=123&y=456`.

On this second page you want to read these values, so you need to parse the querystring which is located in `window.location.search`. There are various ways of doing this, but no built-in feature (it will always be a string, for example `x=123&y=456` that you need to parse). I will leave that open as you mention it is a school project and that last bit would be the next challenge ;)

(`localStorage` as described by @remdevtec is also an option of course.)

Comment: Thanks man both urs and remdevtec's solution are working perfectly :-)